# Ansible: compare two arrays by specific field

Tags: ansible, list-comparison

I have two arrays with applications descriptions:

```
source_array:
  - status: Active
    AppName": "Application 1"
    version: "0.1.1"
    metadata: ""
  - status": "Active"
    AppName: "Application 2"
    version: "0.2.2"
    metadata: "ID123"
  - status: "Active"
    AppName: "Application 3"
    version: "0.3.3"
    metadata: ""
```

And:

```
target_array:
  - status: "Active"
    AppName: "Application 1"
    version: "0.1.1"
    metadata: ""
  - status: "Active"
    AppName: "Application 2"
    version: "0.2.2"
    metadata: "ID321"
  - status: "Active",
    AppName: "Application 3"
    version: "0.3.0"
    metadata: ""
```

I need to compare these two arrays based on the version field.
So, for example, the desired result should be:

```
[{
    "status": "Active",
    "AppName": "Application 3",
    "version": "0.3.0",
    "metadata": ""
}]
```

I've tried to use difference filter but it returns also the secondf element - as it has different metadata

```
- name: Comparing arrays
  set_fact:
    delta: "{{ source_array | difference(target_array) }}"
```

And i've got incorrect result:

```
[{
    "status": "Active",
    "AppName": "Application 2",
    "version": "0.2.2",
    "metadata": "ID123"
},
{
    "status": "Active",
    "AppName": "Application 3",
    "version": "0.3.3",
    "metadata": ""
},
{
    "status": "Active",
    "AppName": "Application 2",
    "version": "0.2.2",
    "metadata": "ID321"
},
{
    "status": "Active",
    "AppName": "Application 3",
    "version": "0.3.0",
    "metadata": ""
}]
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/Klarrio/ansible-dotdiff is a solution for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This not trivial indeed. You don't provide much context but I suspect what you want to do is something like check if an application has been or should be updated. Right ?

Here is one way:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    array1:
      - status: "Active"
        AppName: "Application 1"
        version: "0.1.1"
        metadata: ""
      - status: "Active"
        AppName: "Application 2"
        version: "0.2.2"
        metadata: "ID321"
      - status: "Active"
        AppName: "Application 3"
        version: "0.3.3"
        metadata: ""
    array2:
      - status: "Active"
        AppName: "Application 1"
        version: "0.1.1"
        metadata: ""
      - status: "Active"
        AppName: "Application 2"
        version: "0.2.2"
        metadata: "ID321"
      - status: "Active"
        AppName: "Application 3"
        version: "0.3.0"
        metadata: ""

  tasks:
    - name: "Show matching pattern"
      debug:
        msg: "{{'^' + (array1|map(attribute='version'))|difference(array2|map(attribute='version'))|join('|') + '$'}}"

    - name: "Compare arrays"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ array1 | selectattr('version', 'match', '^' + (array1|map(attribute='version'))|difference(array2|map(attribute='version'))|join('|') + '$') | list }}"
```

It works by first finding the "newer versions", then screening the original list based on those. But it is a bit brittle cause:

- it assumes you now, *a priori* which array contains  the "newer" data (here all newer version are in `array1`).
- if you have two or more elements in your array with identical versions it would retain both, not knowing which to chose.

Maybe you should consider a different data structure, like a mapping (dict). See the `current_state` variable below:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    current_state:
      "Application 1":
        status: "Active"
        version: "0.1.1"
        metadata: ""
      "Application 2":
        status: "Active"
        version: "0.2.2"
        metadata: "ID321"
      "Application 3":
        status: "Active"
        version: "0.3.0"
        metadata: ""
    new_applications:
      - status: "Active"
        AppName: "Application 1"
        version: "0.1.1"
        metadata: ""
      - status: "Active"
        AppName: "Application 2"
        version: "0.2.2"
        metadata: "ID321"
      - status: "Active"
        AppName: "Application 3"
        version: "0.3.3"
        metadata: ""
      - status: "Active"
        AppName: "Application 4"
        version: "0.1.0"
        metadata: ""
  tasks:
    - name: "Different appraoch"
      debug:
         msg: "{{ item.0 }} -- {{ item.1 }} -- Should update: {{ item.1.version is version((current_state[item.0]|default({'version': '0.0.0'}))['version'], '>') }}"
      loop: "{{ new_applications|map(attribute='AppName')|zip(new_applications)|list }}"

    - name: "Build 'current_state' from a list (if not available as is)"
      # There might be a smarter way using items2dict...
      set_fact:
        dict_from_list: "{{ dict_from_list|default({})|combine({item[0]: item[1]})}}"
      loop: "{{ new_applications|map(attribute='AppName')|zip(new_applications)|list }}"

    - debug:
        var: dict_from_list
```

This version fixes the last of the two issues mentioned above. It is also more robust in case the order of the two arrays are not the same, or the array do not have the same length.

The first issue I chose to ignore because, though your question lead to believe `array1` and `array2` to be interchangeable, I am assuming they are in fact not, within a given context.

Comment: Perfect!
Basically, both issues are what i need to achieve.
This playbook is to deploy packages from one environment to another - from DEV to TESTING, so first array is always has newer versions - no matter higher it or lower.
And if it will leave both items with the same version - also perfect, as in real world i have there some other options in the item - and it is possible that i will have more than one appication with the same version but different option.
Thank you so much for your solution!

Comment: @user41995 Then, would you consider accepting the answer ? Thank you.